# Divide the content of a text document into categories, and view a partial text

Tags: ms-office, filtering, openoffice.org

When I go over a text document ,I divide the content into different categories by highlighting sentences with different colors.

I would like to have the ability to create a set of categories , and then go over the text and mark a sentence and assign it to one of the categories.
and then have the option to see a filtered text, that contains only the sentences of one or more categories.

I would like to find out ,whether open-office or microsoft office support this, and if not, if there are plugins for that, and if not, to have some directions for how to use the api of open office for that.

Answer (score 2):

Using colors would make this difficult, but in Microsoft Office (for example) you can use styles as a starting point. Create multiple styles, each of which have a meaningful name (such as "Important", "Irrelevant" or "Miscategorized") and associated each style with a color.

You can then create a macro fairly easily which will hide the style you don't want to see. Or you can temporarily change the colors or the font sizes to be invisible.